# How to make ruby loops wait for 15 min after each 300 element?

Tags: ruby, loops

I want to make ruby script that will print all followers for any account, but twitters API will gife me an error (too many requests) after 300 printed follower, how can i make loop to print the frist 300 then wait for 15 min then to start where its done to another 300?

Comment: and how to make it run every 300 element

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like:

```
some_variable = 0
loop do 
  #**your code that puts element ** 
  some_variable += 1
  sleep(15*60) if (some_variable % 300).zero?
end
```